# read specific columns in a object format in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have to read some specific columns in hibernate. I have written a method like this

```
Branch getBranch(long branchId)
{
    String query = "select distinct bran.branch.branchId,bran.branch.branchName from Location bran where bran.branch.branchId =:branchId";
    Session session = getSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query buildQuery =  getSession().createQuery(query).setParameter("branchId", branchId);
    List<Object[]> countryList = buildQuery.list();
    Branch branch = null;
    for(Object[] obj : countryList)
    {
        branch  = new Branch((Long)obj[0] , (String)obj[1]);
    }
    session.close();
    return branch;
}
```

But here I have to construct the object manually which i don't want. I want to read the result in object form and i dont want manual construction of object. My entity is like this

```
public final class Location  implements Comparable<Location>{

    @Id
    @Column(name = Tables.LOCATION.LOCATION_ID, nullable = false, precision = 15, scale = 0, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private long locationId;

    @Column(name = Tables.LOCATION.LOCATION_NAME, length = 60, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private String locationName;

    @Embedded
    private Country country;

    @Embedded
    private Branch branch;
```

Branch does not map to an entity whereas it is embeddable. I want to read the data in form of DTO so i have gone through ResultTransformer class but it workd only with sqlQuery not with HQL(Correct me if i am wrong). I cant change my query .Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate can do this for you by using the `new` keyword ([called dynamic instantiation/constructor expression](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e3282)) in the HQL:

Just change your query to:

```
select new your.package.name.Branch(bran.branch.branchId,bran.branch.branchName) from Location bran where bran.branch.branchId =:branchId
```

Comment: Thanks Aleksander..It working fine but let me know that package.className is always required even when i am calling it from same package Because have tried this way before and it was not working when i used just class name alone.